# node typescript : regex to allow whitespace with at least one alphanum caracter with joi validation

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, joi

I am using joi and regex to validate user input, I would like to accept only alpha num caracters where whitespace can be allowed. I've done the following :

```
const schema = Joi.object({
  value: Joi.string()
    .regex(
      /^[a-zA-Z0-9 ]*$/,
      'message',
    )
    .max(100)
    .required()
...
```

The problem is that now I allow user to fill a full string composed only of whitespaces, and that's not what I want, I accept whitespaces, only if they are between alphanum caracters. I am using this to test : https://www.regextester.com/104025

Answer (score 1):

Try this one:

```
/^[a-zA-Z0-9]+[a-zA-Z0-9 ]*[a-zA-Z0-9]+$/
```

I dont know if this is the easiest or most elegant way but `[a-zA-Z0-9]+`  matches **one or more** of `[a-zA-Z0-9]` using the `+`

I added this to the front and end of your regex.

Test and explanation:
https://regex101.com/r/79uEWb/2/

Answer (score 0):

Specify at the beginning that space is not allowed `[^ ]`

```js
const withSpaceInFront = " hello";
const text = "hello there"
const textAndNumbers = "hello 5"
const textWithSpecialChars = "hello#"
const numeric = 123

const textWithSpecialCharsAllowed = "general Kenobi..?"


const regexNoSpace = /^[^ ][a-zA-Z0-9 ]*$/;

console.log("no space in front")
console.log(regexNoSpace.test(withSpaceInFront));
console.log(regexNoSpace.test(text));
console.log(regexNoSpace.test(textAndNumbers));
console.log(regexNoSpace.test(textWithSpecialChars));
console.log(regexNoSpace.test(numeric));

//if you want to accept special chars like ? or . just add them in your list of accepted chars

const regexAllowedSpecialChars = /^[^ ][a-zA-Z0-9 ?.]*$/;

console.log("no space in front & specific chars allowed")
console.log(regexAllowedSpecialChars.test(textWithSpecialCharsAllowed));
```

Regex tests:  https://regex101.com/r/8Ulpu9/1/